# Как в Laravel для валидации сделать несколько вариантов для одного поля?

Tags: php, laravel, валидация

Нужно что бы поле было или строкой, причём содержаться в определённом поле или быть файлом, или быть пустым. Как это реализовать?

(Валидацию делаю через FormRequest)

Comment: Используйте метод [withValidator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests) где опишите всю ваше логику, либо сделайте свой [кастомный валидатор](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное вы планируете передавать Base64 кодированную строку или файл.
Было бы правильно разделить эти значения на 2 отдельных параметра, потому что отношение к ним разное.

Как ответил @Total Pusher, можете создать кастомное правило или добавить метод withValidator() в ваш потомок FormRequest. Кастомное правило более правильный для переиспользования кода.

Пример с withValidator

```
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
                if (...) {
                    $validator->errors()->add('branch_id', 'Не может быть изменен');
                }
        });
    }
```

Custom Rule

```
class SomeRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //Здесь не нужно проверять пустой ли $value
        //Здесь $value всегда не пустой

        //Полагаю что в вашем случае $value будет либо экземпляром File либо строкой

        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```

И в вашем потомке FormRequest добавляется правило

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'field' => ['nullable', new SomeRule()],
            ...
        ];
    }
```